# How do I actually handle auth with JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, authorization

For a past few days, I'm trying to learn how to actually do auth for my apps.
I'm building fullstack blog app, which consists of API server and Client server.

- API server is node/express that handles database interactions and auth.
- Client is just a frontend made with React.

I'm trying to do auth with JWT tokens, so my thought process is this =>

1. User uses client app to register with form and then fetches the data with POST method to the API.
2. The API checks if the data is valid to be registered. If yes, it creates database entry and a JWT token.
3. ??? Now what? I want the token to be stored in the cookie, but I don't really understand how or when to do that. Do I just send the created token back from the API to the client and then create a new cookie, or can I create the cookie through the API and somehow send the cookie back to the client? I'm just a newbie trying to learn, so I understand if I don't really make sense, however any help or guidance will be apriciated. Thank you.

I tried to send the token as a JSON and then create cookie on the client side, but I dont know if this is a proper way to do this.

Comment: Basically, the JWT token is used for authentication, my suggestion is While the user signs create the JWT and store it in the database and send it with the response header. Whenever a user makes a private API call, from the back-end side you need to get that token from the request header and validate that, (If that token is not present in the request you need to throw the error).
If anything comment below, and we will discuss

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.